# Impossible to start Apache service due to SSL library error

Tags: apache-httpd, openssl, https

I am trying to configure Apache in order to accept HTTPS requests.
Following some tutorials found online, I generated the following certificates:

1. my-ca.key (CA private key)
2. my-ca.crt (CA certificate)
3. my-server.key (server private key)
4. my-server.csr (server certificate signing request)
5. my-server.crt (server certificate)

In particular, the last certificate have been generated using the following command:

```
openssl x509 -req  -sha1 -in my-server.csr -out my-server.crt -CA my-ca.crt -CAkey my-ca.key -CAcreateserial
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to start the Apache service because, mentioning the `error.log` file content:

```
[Sun Apr 05 01:00:23.831320 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 1463] AH02561: Failed to configure certificate localhost:443:0, check /etc/ssl/my-certs/my-server.crt 
[Sun Apr 05 01:00:23.832228 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 1463] SSL Library Error: error:140AB18E:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate:ca md too weak 
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

Searching for a solution on Google, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52220373) useful answer on StackOverflow, but as you can check above, I have already used an hashing algorithm different from `md5` (in my case, `sha1`) for the server certificate generation.

So, why this error keep to be returned when starting Apache service? Should I also create a new CA certificate and/or server certificate request?

Comment: Check your config for an SSLCipherSuite directive that (also) specifies @SECLEVEL . If > 1 that prohibits SHA1-signed cert; either change the config (if possible and acceptable) or change your server cert signature (but not the request or the CA cert)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, I found the following SSLCipherSuite directive only in `mods-available/ssl.conf`: `SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL`. Should I overwrite it? Anyway, no @SECLEVEL found.

Comment: If it doesn't have @SECLEVEL it's not related to this problem, so let it be. To try to isolate, try running comandline `openssl s_server` with the same files as you gave Apache and see if that works. (If you used SSLCertificateChainFile, or a version that accepts a chain in SSLCertificateFile, which you probably shouldn't need for this simple 2-level setup, OpenSSL must be 1.1.0 up with `-cert_chain` to match this.) If commandline gives the error we have a simpler case to look at; if not you need to look in mod_ssl which is probably harder.